# NextAuth.js getServerSession return null even after user is sign in

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I try to implement protected route in Next.js using NextAuth.js

inside my API i use getServerSession method to fetch login user.
Now i use it inside getServerSideProps getServerSession works for first time but when i use fetched session and make a API call it return a nell and get a 401 error.

But when i make the same api call in browser it fetched session as you see in screenshot below
[fetched session from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a5wl.png)

Here is my code..

```
//My frontend code
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions); //It works properly

  if (session) {
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/profile/${session.user.uid}`); //But can't able to fetch session from REST API it return a status code 401
      return {
        props: {
          user: data,
        },
      };
    } catch (error) {}
  }

  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: "/api/auth/signin",
      permanent: false,
    },
  };
}



//Backend code
export default async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);

  if (!session)
    return res.status(401).json({
      error: "unauthenticated user is not allowed.",
    });

  try {
    await connectToDB();
  } catch (error) {
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json({ error: "server can't able to connect to DB." });
  }

  const {
    method,
    query: { id },
  } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const user = await User.findById(id);
        if (user) res.status(200).json(user);
        else res.status(500).json({ error: "No user found for the given id." });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
          error: error.message,
        });
      }
      break;
    default:
      res.status(501).json({ error: "Invalid Request." });
  }
};
```

Here what i want is first getServerSession fetch session first time and use that session data to make a API call. (which work correctly)
But after fetched session i make a API call and inside my API call i again check if user is login (to protect API route also) but it return 401 error.

Now if i made that API call using browser it fetched my session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Next.js when working with `getServerSideProps` it accepts a `context` parameter.
You have to manually add a cookie header when doing an API request.

Like This:

```js
const response = await Axios.get(`/api/profile/${uid}`, {
    headers: {
        Cookie: context.req.headers.cookie,
    },
});
```